# Scrapy appears to be deduplicating the first request when it is processed with DownloaderMiddleware

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

I've got a certain spider which inherits from `SitemapSpider`. As expected, the first request on startup is to `sitemap.xml` of my website. However, for it to work correctly I need to add a header to all the requests, including the initial ones which fetch the sitemap. I do so with DownloaderMiddleware, like this:

```
def process_request(self, request: scrapy.http.Request, spider):
    if "Host" in request.headers:
        return None

    host = request.url.removeprefix("https://").removeprefix("http://").split("/")[0]
    request.headers["Host"] = host
    spider.logger.info(f"Got {request}")
    return request
```

However, looks like Scrapy's request deduplicator is stopping this request from going through. In my logs I see something like this:

```
2021-10-16 21:21:08 [ficbook-spider] INFO: Got <GET https://mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml>
2021-10-16 21:21:08 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml>
```

Since `spider.logger.info` in `process_request` is triggered only once, I presume that it is the first request, and, after processing, it gets deduplicated. I thought that, maybe, deduplication is triggered before DownloaderMiddleware (that would explain that the request is deduplicated without a second "Got ..." in logs), however, I don't think that's true for two reasons:

- I looked through the code of SitemapSpider, and it appears to fetch the sitemap.xml only once
- If it did, in fact, fetch it before, I'd expect it to do something - instead it just stops the spider, since no pages were enqueued for processing

Why does this happen? Did I make some mistake in `process_request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't do something with the first response and neither fetch a second response since you are returning a new request from your custom DownloaderMiddleware `process_request` function which is being filtered out. From the docs:

> If it returns a Request object, Scrapy will stop calling
> process_request methods and reschedule the returned request. Once the
> newly returned request is performed, the appropriate middleware chain
> will be called on the downloaded response.

It might work if you explicitly say to not filter your second request.

```
def process_request(self, request: scrapy.http.Request, spider):
    if "Host" in request.headers:
        return None

    host = request.url.removeprefix("https://").removeprefix("http://").split("/")[0]
    new_req = request.replace(dont_filter=True)
    new_req.headers["Host"] = host
    spider.logger.info(f"Got {new_req}")
    return new_req
```